# Config file finding unexpected $end, not sure why

Tags: linux, monitoring, collectd

I am using a custom config of collectd and for some reason I keep getting a failure when I try and run the service. Originally I had everything in one big file, but to make changing configs easier I want to separate out the settings for various plugins and components. Collectd has a `Include` option to do exactly this. It seems to work, but when collectd tries to grab the external part of the program I get the following error:

```
Parse error in file `/etc/collectd/collectd.conf.d/http.conf', line 1100 near `': syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting EOL
```

If I go in and copy paste direct into the server using vim, it will work. However when the package installs it won't. I know these kinds of errors can come from mismatched brackets or quotes or something, but his is not a problem in these files. Is there anything else which could cause such an error?

Answer (score 7):

For the users they have similar error at you. For my case, i have not return line at the bottom of collectd.conf or plugins configuration files. For verify, you can use this command

```
$ xxd collectd.conf | tail -n1 | grep 0a

00001c0: 730a 0a                                  s..
```

You must see the `0a` at the end of the file

**Note :** You can replace collectd.conf by plugins configuration files

Comment: I wasted a couple of hours until I figured this out. And this is the only reference I have found on the entire internet to this problem. This is in my opinion a bug on collectd, because their documentation says nothing about requiring newlines at the end of the file.